# jQuery Plugin for pulling a Facebook feed (RSS) into webpage?

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like a quick and dirty way of including a feed from facebook (posts or/and comments, images if possible) on a site but don't want to use FB's standard 'like box'.

So, I found this:
http://jquery-plugins.net/FeedEk/FeedEk.html

Is there anything else better out there? I've seen other jQuery RSS readers but they seem to require extra server side scripts to actually grab the data. This plugin above is pure JS though I can't tell exactly how it's getting the info (without generating some sort of security warning?)

Answer (score 0):

FeedEk is just for regular RSS feeds. If you want to pull a facebook feed you will have to create an app, because an access token is needed for this. So, either there is a plugin that uses an app already and you are giving away the oppertunity for insights/statistics to another programmer, or you do it on your own with the PHP SDK:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

It is quite easy, and you only need an app access token, no user login.

```
$app_accesstoken = APP-ID . '|' . APP-SECRET;
```

(You don´t really need this, without a user login it should already be set if you use the PHP SDK)

Here´s the download for the PHP SDK, and a small tutorial of the usage if you scroll down:

> https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk